# While running the go test under a package, how to skip a go file at test as well as at coverage report

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go

I want to skip a particular go file under a package, while running the **go test** and coverage.
Please find the below command, I have used to run under my service package :

```
cd src/service && go test --coverprofile coverageService.out --coverpkg ./.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no simple way to skip tests based solely on the file name, however, here are three simple options which may work:

**1. Specify tests using a regular expression**

The go test command supports the `-run` runtime option which only runs tests satisfying a regular expression:

> -run regexp
>
> Run only those tests and examples matching the regular expression.
>     For tests, the regular expression is split by unbracketed slash (/)
>     characters into a sequence of regular expressions, and each part
>     of a test's identifier must match the corresponding element in
>     the sequence, if any. Note that possible parents of matches are
>     run too, so that -run=X/Y matches and runs and reports the result
>     of all tests matching X, even those without sub-tests matching Y,
>     because it must run them to look for those sub-tests.

In order for this to work, you will need to name all of the tests in the file in question in such a way that you can exclude them via a regular expression (for example, make all of them start with `TestExcludable...`, such as `TestExcludableA`, `TestExludableB`, etc). Then run using a slightly hacky negative regular expression, such as `-run "Test[^E][^x][^c][^l][^u][^d][^a][^b][^l][^e].*"`

**2. Don't compile certain tests using build flags**

As explained in detail in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24036237/353184), you can use build flags to prevent a particular file from building as part of the test suite. In a nutshell,

**skip_test.go**

```
// +build !skipset1
package name

import testing

// Rest of test file
```

Then when you invoke `go test` us the `-tags` parameter and specify the tests you would like to skip, such as `-tags skipset1`.

**3. Rename the offending file during the build**

As specified in the go test docs,

> Files whose names begin with "_" (including "_test.go") or "." are ignored.

Simply surround your go test command with a rename so that the file to skip is not actually compiled into the test executable:

`mv src/skip_test.go src/_skip_test.go && go test ... || mv src/_skip_test.go src/skip_test.go`

(note the use of an `||` and in the second move, to cause it to run even if the go test fails).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @jwriteclub I am able to skip the test cases, but i am not able to exclude those method present on the skipset1 file, while running the -coverprofile

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you want the coverage tool not to cover the code called by the skipped tests?

Comment: yes,the tool should cover all the files present under the package except  the file tagged as skipped test

Comment: Then I think you'll need to use the build flags. If the code in question isn't built, then it's not getting covered.