# Running a main-like in a non-main package

Tags: testing, go, program-entry-point

We have a package with a fair number of complex tests. As part of the test suite, they run on builds etc.

```
 func TestFunc(t *testing.T) {
    //lots of setup stuff and defining success conditions
    result := SystemModel.Run()
 }
```

Now, for one of these tests, I want to introduce some kind of frontend which will make it possible for me to debug a few things. It's not really a test, but a debug tool. For this, I want to just run the same test but with a Builder pattern:

```
 func TestFuncWithFrontend(t *testing.T) {
    //lots of setup stuff and defining success conditions
    result := SystemModel.Run().WithHTTPFrontend(":9999")
 }
```

The test then would only start if I send a signal via HTTP from the frontend. Basically `WithHTTPFrontend()` just waits with a channel on a HTTP call from the frontend.

This of course would make the automated tests fail, because no such signal will be sent and execution will hang.

I can't just rename the package to `main` because the package has 15 files and they are used elsewhere in the system.

Likewise I haven't found a way to run a test only on demand while excluding it from the test suite, so that `TestFuncWithFrontend` would only run from the commandline - I don't care if with `go run` or `go test` or whatever.

I've also thought of `ExampleTestFunc()` but there's so much output produced by the test it's useless, and without defining `Output: ...`, the Example won't run.

Unfortunately, there's also a lot of initialization code at (private, i.e. lower case) package level that the test needs. So I can't just create a sub-package `main`, as a lot of that stuff wouldn't be accessible.

It seems I have three choices:

1. Export all this initialization variables and code with upper case, so that I could be using it from a sub-main package
2. Duplicate the whole code.
3. Move the test into a sub-package `main` and then have a `func main()` for the test with Frontend and a `_test.go` for the normal test, which would have to import a few things from the parent package.

I'd rather like to avoid the second option...And the first is better, but isn't great either IMHO. I think I'll go for the third, but...

am I missing some other option?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a custom command line argument to `go test` and start the debug port based on that. Something like this:

```
package hello_test

import (
    "flag"
    "log"
    "testing"
)

var debugTest bool

func init() {
    flag.BoolVar(&debugTest, "debug-test", false, "Setup debugging for tests")
}

func TestHelloWorld(t *testing.T) {
    if debugTest {
        log.Println("Starting debug port for test...")
        // Start the server here
    }

    log.Println("Done")
}
```

Then if you want to run just that specific test, `go test -debug-test -run '^TestHelloWorld$' ./`.

Alternatively it's also possible to set a custom environment variable that you check in the test function to change behaviour.

Comment: I actually like this! No additional test needed, and runs the exact same code! I will think about it further and then decide and possibly accept. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it's a nice feature. Though your use case is new, we do use it to enable/disable tests that take time to run or depend on external services. So a quick `go test` could be run quite frequently and a longer, more detailed test could be run if the quick tests pass or before pushing to the repository.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found an acceptable option. This answer

[Skip some tests with go test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030059/skip-some-tests-with-go-test)

brought me to the right track.

Essentially using build tags which would not be present in normal builds but which I can provide when executing manually.