# Exclude a package's test in Windows

Tags: go

I'm running the code below on MacOS and Linux for excluding packages in tests:

```
go test $(go list ./... | grep -v /examples)
```

But this command won't run in Windows.

I'm not so good at windows commands, does anyone know the equivalent of this command in Windows?

Comment: How about using +build tag [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030059/skip-some-tests-with-go-test) It is a means to achieve the purpose without being dependent on the OS.